# Possible to echo an entire command line, including pipe symbols?

Tags: shell-script

It's my standard practice to use this idiom in my shell scripts:

```
doCmd() {
    if $verbose; then echo "$@" >&2; fi
    if $really; then "$@"; fi
}

...

echo Begin whatever this script is doing
doCmd rm -rf test_results_dir
doCmd cd test_results_dir
doCmd run_lengthy_test
```

As you can see, this idiom lets me add "-v" and "-n" options to all my scripts and near-seamlessly echo the commands to stdout before I run them, and/or suppress actual execution of my commands. I think this is a fairly common idiom.

But here's where I get stuck:

```
doCmd tail -n +2 test.log | grep total > summary.log
```

Obviously, this runs `doCmd tail -n +2 test.log`, and pipes its output through grep. But what I really want to happen is to echo that entire line, '|' and all to stdout, and then run it as written.

Is this reasonably easily do-able, or am I asking too much of the shell?

Comment: Why not run the interpreter with `-n` & `-v`? E.g. `bash -nv your_script`, or `set -n` & `set -v` in the script when parsing options.

Comment: I was thinking of using -v or -x. Let me see if -n will work too.